# MySQL, SELECT e JOIN em tabelas com colunas NULL

Tags: mysql

Pessoal gostaria de ajuda com meu BD.

Tenho 3 perguntas para responder e consigo responder apenas a 3ª, como respondo as outras?

1) Quais transportadoras estão presentes em apenas 1 categoria?

2) Quais transportadoras estão presentes em 2 categorias?

3) Quais transportadoras estão presentes nas 3 categorias?

Obrigado!

Comment: O que você já tentou que não deu certo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa resposta não é de uma linha mas funciona:

1) Quais transportadoras estão presentes em apenas 1 categoria?

```
SELECT t.Transportadora, v.Preferencia_Nacional_Voto, v.Transporte_Internacional_Voto, v.Transporte_Rodoaereo_Voto
FROM transportadora t
JOIN voto v on t.Id_Transportadora = v.Id_Transportadora
WHERE

(v.Preferencia_Nacional_Voto is null
and
v.Transporte_Internacional_Voto is not null
and
v.Transporte_Rodoaereo_Voto is not null)

OR 

(v.Preferencia_Nacional_Voto is not null
and
v.Transporte_Internacional_Voto is null
and
v.Transporte_Rodoaereo_Voto is not null)

OR 

(v.Preferencia_Nacional_Voto is not null
and
v.Transporte_Internacional_Voto is not null
and
v.Transporte_Rodoaereo_Voto is null);
```

---

2) Quais transportadoras estão presentes em 2 categorias?

```
SELECT t.Transportadora, v.Preferencia_Nacional_Voto, v.Transporte_Internacional_Voto, v.Transporte_Rodoaereo_Voto
FROM transportadora t
JOIN voto v on t.Id_Transportadora = v.Id_Transportadora
WHERE

(v.Preferencia_Nacional_Voto is null
and
v.Transporte_Internacional_Voto is null
and
v.Transporte_Rodoaereo_Voto is not null)

OR 

(v.Preferencia_Nacional_Voto is null
and
v.Transporte_Internacional_Voto is not null
and
v.Transporte_Rodoaereo_Voto is null)

OR 

(v.Preferencia_Nacional_Voto is not null
and
v.Transporte_Internacional_Voto is null
and
v.Transporte_Rodoaereo_Voto is null);
```

Comment: Obrigado Edney! Depois que postei minha dúvida consegui resolver com apoio do meu irmão que é de TI, seguimos o mesmo raciocínio alterando apenas algumas coisas mas a resposta foi a mesma.